# EF 5 - Model first database migration: change model after published to remote production server?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm developing in MVC 5, EF 5.0 code first. I publish the project using file sharing folder.

I can use database migration to update the developing localDb when the model is changed. However, after I published the project to a remote server, it shows the error of models being changed and migration required on the production web server which use a full SQL database server.

I know I can delete the database on the production server and let it recreates the database. However, there are already user entered data in the tables.

Is there a way to apply the model/database changes without recreate the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is a way. Actually there are several.

- You can generate a SQL script that can be applied to the production database. Run the Update-Database in the Package Manager Console with the -Script flag like so:

  Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: InitialMigration -TargetMigration: LatestMigration

  Or use a tool like Red Gate SQL Compare to generate the script.
- On Application startup you can automatically upgrade the database by registering the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion database initializer:

  Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion());

You can read more about both methods in the article [MSDN - Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621).

Answer (score 0):

I never had the option to delete the database on the production. EF code first is not for that purpose, it's for development only,

There are a couple of options, if you use Visual Studio Ultimate, there is a schema compare tool under SQL Menu. Alternatively, you can use Red Gate SQL Compare tools.

Comment: I'm using the VS Pro. Can I manually update production database tables so Asp.Net will not complain "Model changed and need migration"?

Comment: Make sure that you have the same hash value in migration table